# How i can append my data in nested Object?

Tags: javascript, object, nested

```
let users = {
    142201801: {
        name: "Pankaj Jaiswal",
        address: "Om sai rcm shopy , 400089",
        accountType: "Saving",
        deposits: 20000,
        withdraws: 15000,
        balance: 5000
    },
    142201802: {
        name: "John Deo",
        address: "Om sai rcm shopy , 400089",
        accountType: "Saving",
        deposits: 20000,
        withdraws: 15000,
        balance: 5000
    }
};
let accountNumber_inital = 142201805;

function accountMaker() {
    let accountNumber = accountNumber_inital + 1;
    let name = document.getElementById("userName").value;
    let address = document.getElementById("userAddress").value;
    let type = document.getElementById("accoutType").value;
    console.log("Account made");
}
```

I have a Object of users i already added 2 user by hardcoding .

My Object is nested Object, first key is account number of user and i nested their data in other Object.
 What i want is to added other users from input filed .I Am accepting users name , address and account type .

I want to append the data to my users Object just after my other users . I already tried append but it giving me error of .append is not function .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a JavaScript object, not a list or an array so you can't push to it. You can however, define a new key with it's associated value like so:

```
users[accountNumber] = {
  name,
  address,
  accountType: type,
  deposits: 0,
  withdraws: 0,
  balance: 0
};
```

And if you wanted to remove an object you could do

```
delete users[accountNumber]
```

It's important to remember that JavaScript objects like yours effectively act as a dictionary (key/value pairs), where an array is just a list. If you wanted the behaviour of a list then you could change your object definition slightly to look like:

```
let users = [
  {
    accountNumber: '123',
    otherFields: ''
  }
];

users.push({accountNumber: '1234', otherFields: 'test'});
```

However then you would lose the ability to directly access the object by the account number, it all depends what best suits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `append` since it's an Object but you can use `Object.assign` https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/assign to add your newly created object

Or just do `users[accountNumber] = {yourObject}`

Answer (score 0):

withot using `append` you can use add new item (user) to the current object (users) like below.

```
function accountMaker() {
    let accountNumber = accountNumber_inital + 1;
    let name = document.getElementById("userName").value;
    let address = document.getElementById("userAddress").value;
    let type = document.getElementById("accoutType").value;
    console.log("Account made");

    // add to the users dictionary

    users.accountNumber = {
        name: name ,
        address: address ,
        accountType: type ,
        deposits: 0,
        withdraws: 0,
        balance: 0
    }
}
```

Comment: That would add an entry like `{accountNumber: obj}` instead of the actual account number. It should look like `users[accountNumber]` as in my answer above.

Comment: it worked if i am inserting name if  i inserted name and address it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this way:

```js
let users = {
    142201801: {
        name: "Pankaj Jaiswal",
        address: "Om sai rcm shopy , 400089",
        accountType: "Saving",
        deposits: 20000,
        withdraws: 15000,
        balance: 5000
    },
    142201802: {
        name: "John Deo",
        address: "Om sai rcm shopy , 400089",
        accountType: "Saving",
        deposits: 20000,
        withdraws: 15000,
        balance: 5000
    }
};
let accountNumber_inital = 142201805;
function add_user(id,name,address,accountType,deposits,withdraws,balance){
    var obj = {};
    obj.name = name;
    obj.address = address;
    obj.accountType = accountType;
    obj.deposits = deposits;
    obj.withdraws = withdraws;
    obj.balance = balance;
    //check id
    if(users.hasOwnProperty(id)===true){
        //id exist, let update
        Object.assign(users.id,obj);
    }else{
        //id not exist, let add
        users[id] = obj;
    }
}
add_user(accountNumber_inital+1,"new John Deo", "new Om sai rcm shopy , 400089", "new Saving", 20000, 15000, 6000);
console.log(users);
```